# Access on prem sql server without VMs through azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-private-link

Currently I have SHIR in vm which has virtual network set up to connect to on prem sql for my data factory. I want to get rid of the VM and still access the onprem sql using the virtual network. Is it possible to use private link service to pull the data from onprem using adf managed private endpoint? I found one resource where they do this using a VM on top of the private link service. However, that still requires a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to use a private link service and a managed private endpoint to access an on-premises SQL Server instance from ADF.

Using the private IP address, you can use the managed private endpoint to connect to the on-prem SQL Server. This eliminates the use of VM.

For this, You need to create a [virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quick-create-portal) and establish a connection to your on-premises network using a [VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json) or [ExpressRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-howto-linkvnet-portal-resource-manager?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json).
Then you need to create a private endpoint for the SQL Server instance and use the private IP address to connect to SQL. You need to use SHIR(Which is installed on an on-premises machine and configured to connect to your virtual network) to connect to on-prem SQL via a private network using the private IP of the endpoint.